# HashMap returned by Maps.newHashMap vs new HashMap

Tags: java, spring, collections, guava

I am trying Guava for the first time and I find it really awesome.

I am executing few parameterized retrieve queries on a Spring jdbc template. The method in the DAO (`AbstractDataAccessObject`) goes like this. No problem here.

```
public Map<String,Object> getResultAsMap(String sql, Map<String,Object> parameters) {
    try {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(sql, parameters);
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        //Ignore if no data found for this query
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);

    }
    return null;
}
```

Here's the problem :

When I call this method using

```
getResultAsMap(query, new HashMap<String,Object>(ImmutableMap.of("gciList",gciList)));
```

it works great.

But when I do this

```
getResultAsMap(query, Maps.newHashMap(ImmutableMap.of("gciList",gciList)));
```

the compiler gets upset saying

`The method getResultAsMap(String, Map<String,Object>) in the type AbstractDataAccessObject is not applicable for the arguments (String, HashMap<String,List<String>>)`

Am I doing something wrong or what could be the reason for this complaint?

Comment: Probably You should cast gciList on Object => (Object)gciList before putting it as argument

Comment: As mykhaylo said, the problem is that the signatures don't match for the type arguments- you expect a Map<String, Object>, but provide a Map<String, List<String>> - casting the list to object works, but a better solution would probably be to either use wildcards (if you reuse that method), add a type parameter to the helper method, or just fix the signature to require the type you actually get.

Comment: @mykhaylo Great. Typecasting works. And great suggestion Sebastian. I should be introducing a type parameter. But tell me one thing why doesn't List<String> get accommodated inside an Object?

Comment: @ArunManivannan it does not work that way because you would then get a Map<String, Object> in which you could add arbitrary objects, however it should contain only Lists of strings! It should work with something like Map<String, ? extends Object> - because this can be assigned a Map<String, List<String>>...

Comment: @Sebastian Nicely explained. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is type inference failing. `Maps.newHashMap` is a static parameterized method. It allows you to use

```
Map<String,Integer> map = Maps.newHashMap()
```

instead of

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>()
```

saving you from having to type `<String,Integer>` twice. In Java 7, the diamond operator allows you to use

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>()
```

so the method is then redundant.

To answer your question, just use the `new HashMap` version, since type inference doesn't work for method parameters. (You could use `Maps.<String,Object>newHashMap()` but that defeats the point of using the method)

Comment: Maybe it's worth linking and quoting Guava's JavaDocs: http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#newHashMap-- _"Note for Java 7 and later: this method is now unnecessary and should be treated as deprecated. Instead, use the HashMap constructor directly, taking advantage of the new "diamond" syntax."_

Answer (score 4):

Adding a late answer here:

Most of the benefit is gone before type inference came to java. (yay) but I was wondering about any performance differences. Here is the code for `google.common.collect.maps`

```
  /**
   * Creates a <i>mutable</i>, empty {@code HashMap} instance.
   *
   * <p><b>Note:</b> if mutability is not required, use {@link
   * ImmutableMap#of()} instead.
   *
   * <p><b>Note:</b> if {@code K} is an {@code enum} type, use {@link
   * #newEnumMap} instead.
   *
   * @return a new, empty {@code HashMap}
   */
  public static <K, V> HashMap<K, V> newHashMap() {
    return new HashMap<K, V>();
  }
```

Its the same code.

Comment: @fordperfect, there are performance differences. i tried adding 100 objects to map created using guava and jdk, guava took 20-25 milliseconds where as jdk took 1 millisecond.

Comment: @hardeepthakur this inherently makes sense considering one is native to the jdk while the other is calling a library. You are doing an extra indirection but the code itself is the same. Again as I said in the answer the reason this exists at all is due to lack of type inference before java 8

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that your method takes `Map<String, Object>`, but that's not actually what you want. You want a `Map` of `String` keys to *any* kind of values. That's not `Map<String, Object>`, it's `Map<String, ?>`.

Comment: Thanks @ColinD Clearly explained.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I misread the compiler error - sorry! Feel free to delete my answer!

What is the exact type of "Map" - is it really java.util.Map and the exact type of HashMap - is it really java.util.HashMap? There seems to be a mismatch here.

Original "answer": Obviously Maps.newHashMap returns an implementation of the Map interface, which is unknown, however getResultAsMap requires a HashMap (which is an unusual requirement). getResultAsMap should be refactored to accept the interface, rather than a concrete implementation, instead.

Comment: No worries Sebastin. I checked and cross checked. All points to java.util package. Unless Guava returns a HashMap which does not implement Map interface, this should work. I checked the source and it does looks good.

Comment: @ArunManivannan: See my comment above - below your question - the problem is the mismatching type arguments.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian. Appreciate your help.