# How to specify target type for collection literals?

Tags: java, collections, literals, xtend

I'm trying to use a target type to specify a collection literal's type:

```
val java.util.HashMap<String,String> map = #{
  'a' -> 'b'
}
```

But I get:

```
HelloWorld.java:212: error: incompatible types: Set<Object> cannot be converted to HashMap<String,String>
    final HashMap<String, String> map = Collections.<Object>unmodifiableSet(CollectionLiterals.<Object>newHashSet(_mappedTo, _mappedTo_1, _mappedTo_2, _mappedTo_3));
```

Note that this is a java compilation error, not an Xtend one. For some reason Xtend is trying to generate a `Set` even though the target type is a `HashMap`.

However, if I change the target type to `Map`, it generates a map as expected.

The [Xtend docs](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/203_xtend_expressions.html) say

> In addition xtend supports collection literals to create immutable collections and arrays, depending on the target type

so I thought I could control the type of unmodifiable map I get back.

Xtend version: 2.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that way you want - implicit conversion won't change the type of map literal for you (bug you are getting is compiler artifact - it gets confused between set of pairs and map literals). What you can do instead is

```
val map = Maps.newHashMap(#{
        'a' -> 'b'
    })
```

which is probably even less typing ;) Maps is from com.google.common.collect, which you will get together with xtend in dependencies.

Comment: Nice. After seeing your answer I found a [similar solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7345751/498594) for pure java.

Answer (score 1):

That quote from [Xtend doc](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/203_xtend_expressions.html#collection-literals):

> In addition xtend supports collection literals to create immutable collections and arrays, depending on the target type.

means **either** a collection, **or** an array — since for both the literal syntax is the same:

```
val myList = #['Hello', 'World']
val String[] myArray = #['Hello', 'World']
```

Sets and maps have both a different syntax, so no need to specify the target type here:

```
val mySet = #{'Hello', 'World'}
val myMap = #{'a' -> 1, 'b' -> 2}
```

If you insist on the target type, use e.g. [**`newHashMap`**](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/javadoc/2.8/org/eclipse/xtext/xbase/lib/CollectionLiterals.html#newHashMap(org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.Pair...)):

```
val myHashMap = newHashMap('a' -> 1, 'b' -> 2)
```